# Convert key from dictionary to int in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
 d = {
  u'71': u' 12.3/0.2mm',
  u'70': u' 12.1/0.2mm', 
  u'79': u' 13.9/0.2mm', 
  u'78': u' 13.7/0.2mm'
 }
```

The keys are currently strings. How can I convert them to integers?

I've tried with `d = {int(k) for k in d}` but it messed up the dictionary, returning only the keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating a new dictionary like that:

```
>>> d = {u'71': u' 12.3/0.2mm', u'70': u' 12.1/0.2mm', u'79': u' 13.9/0.2mm', u'78': u' 13.7/0.2mm'}
>>> 
>>> {int(k): v for k, v in d.items()}
{71: u' 12.3/0.2mm', 70: u' 12.1/0.2mm', 78: u' 13.7/0.2mm', 79: u' 13.9/0.2mm'}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `items()` to iterate on keys and values.

```
d = dict(int(k),v for k,v in d.items())
```

Or the shorter syntax as suggest by Bhargav Rao:

```
d = {int(k),v for k,v in d.items()}
```

Finally as suggested by Manjit Kumar, if your dictionnary does not contains only integer keys:

```
d = {'not an int': 'test', '123': '456'}
new_d = {}
for k,v in d.items():
    try:
        new_d[int(k)] = v
    except ValueError:
        new_d[k] = v
# new_d = {123: '456', 'not an int': 'test'}
```

Comment: Or even `{int(k):v for k,v in d.items()}`

Comment: you may want to put try:catch for ValueError incase all the keys are not int.

Answer (score 1):

You can also work on the dictionary without creating a new one, using the `pop()` method:

```
for k in d:
    d[int(k)] = d.pop(k)
```

Example:

```
>>> d = {u'71': u' 12.3/0.2mm',
         u'70': u' 12.1/0.2mm', 
         u'79': u' 13.9/0.2mm', 
         u'78': u' 13.7/0.2mm'}

>>> for k in d:
        d[int(k)] = d.pop(k)
>>> d
{70: u' 12.1/0.2mm', 71: u' 12.3/0.2mm', 78: u' 13.7/0.2mm', 79: u' 13.9/0.2mm'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
for key in one_dictionary:
   #Do what you want with int(key)
```